# Is performance worse when putting database to a dedicated server?

Tags: performance, web-services, scalability, scalable

I heard that one way to scale your system is to use different machine for web server, database server, and even use multiple instances for each type of server

I wonder how could this improve performance over the one-server-for-everything model? Aren't there bottle necks in the connection between those servers? Moreover, you will have to care about synchronization while accessing the database server from different web server.

Answer (score 3):

If your infrastructure is small enough then yes, 1 server for everything is (probably) the best way to do things, however when your size starts to require that you use more then 1 server, scaling the size of your single box can become much more expensive then having multiple cheaper servers. This also means that you can have more failure tolerance (if one server goes down, the other(s) can take over). As for synchronizing data, on the database side that is usually achieved by using clustering or replicating, on the application side it can be achieved with the likes of memcached or saving to the drive, and web servers themselves don't really need to be synchronized. Network bottlenecks on a local network (like your servers would be from one another) are negligible.

Answer (score 3):

Having numerous servers may appear to be an attractive solution. One problem which often occurs is the latency that arises from communication between the servers. Even with fiber inter-connects it will be slower than if they reside on the same server. Of course, in a single server-solution, if one server application does a lot of work it may starve the DB application of needed CPU resources.

Another issue which may turn up is that of SANs. Proponents of SANs will say that they are just as fast as locally attached storage. The purpose of SANs is to cut costs on storage. Even if the SAN were to use the same high-performance disks as the local solution (wiping out the cost savings) you still have a slower connection and more simultaneous users to contend with on the SAN.

Conventional wisdom has it that a DB should be SQL-based with normalized data. It is worthwile to spend some time weighing pros and cons (yes SQL has cons) against each other.

Since "time-immemorial" (at least the last twenty years) indifferent programmers have overloaded servers with stuff they are too lazy to implement in the client. Indifferent (or ignorant) architects allow this practice to continue. End result: sluggish c/s implementations which are close to useless. Tripling the server park is a desperate "week-before-delivery" measure which - at best - results in a marginal performance increase. Often you lose performance instead.

DBs should not be bothered with complex requests involving multiple tables. Simple requests filtered by the client is the way to go.

One thing to try might be to put framework/SOAP-handling on one server and let it send binary requests to the DB server which answers with binary responses (trying to make sense of a SOAP request is very CPU-intensive and something which you don't want to leave to the DB application which will be more or less choked anyway). This way you'll have SOAP throttling only one part of the environment (the interface to users/other framework users) and the rest of the interfaces will be as efficient as they can be (binary).

Another thing - if the application allows it - is to put a cache front-end on the DB-application. The purpose of this cache is to do as much repetitive stuff as possible without involving the DB itself. This way the DB is left with handling fewer but (perhaps) more complicated requests instead of doing everything.

Oh, don't let clients send SQL statements directly to the DB. You'd be suprised at the junk a DB has to contend with.

Comment: "DBs should not be bothered with complex requests involving multiple tables. Simple requests filtered by the client is the way to go."  I may be misunderstanding, but I strongly disagree.  In my experience, it's best to do as much work as possible in the DB.  Heck, it's *designed* for handling complex queries.  Moving joining/filtering "up" a level to the application, in my experience, slows things down greatly.

Comment: @rinogo: you obviously haven't encountered an overloaded DB-server. When clients send requests that time out after a minute even though the DB-server's RAM-cache is larger than the actual data in the DB? Of course the server is designed for handling complex queries but does that mean that less competent, indifferent or lazy architects and programmers can't bring it to it's knees? Of course not. They do bring it to its knees, it happens everywhere and all the time. It's a question of safety margin: testing solutions beforehand, access rules, following up on performance, keeping amateurs out.